# Here Tracking Device Limit Only 10

Tags: here-api

I would like to know how to add more than 10 devices using here .Will I need to purchase something to do this or is it actually the limit ?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Yes,it is limited to max 10 devices and the limit can only be raised by switching to another plan. please connect our sales team for this.

https://developer.here.com/support-plans